# How to control serial and parallel control flow with mapped functions?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency

I've drawn a simple flow chart, which basically crawls some data from internet and loads them into the database. So far, I had thought I was peaceful with promises, however now I have an issue that I'm working for at least three days without a simple step.

Here is the flow chart:

Consider there is a static string array like so: `const courseCodes = ["ATA, "AKM", "BLG",... ]`.

I have a `fetch` function, it basically does a HTTP request followed by parsing. Afterwards it returns some object array.

`fetch` works perfectly with invoking its callback with that expected object array, it even worked with Promises, which was way greater and tidy.

`fetch` function should be invoked with every element in the `courseCodes` array as its parameter. This task should be performed in parallel execution, since those seperate `fetch` functions do not affect each other.

As a result, there should be a `results` array in callback (or `Promise`s resolve parameter), which includes array of array of objects. With those results, I should invoke my `loadCourse` with those objects in the `results` array as its parameter. Those tasks should be performed in serial execution, because it basically queries database if similar object exists, adds it if it's not.

How can perform this kind of tasks in node.js? I could not maintain the asynchronous flow in such a scenario like this. I've failed with `caolan/async` library and `bluebird` & `q` promise libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, if you are able to understand this:

```
const courseCodes = ["ATA, "AKM", "BLG",... ]

//stores the tasks to be performed.
var parallelTasks = [];
var serialTasks = [];

//keeps track of courses fetched & results.
var courseFetchCount = 0;
var results = {};


//your fetch function.
fetch(course_code){
    //your code to fetch & parse.

    //store result for each course in results object
    results[course_code] = 'whatever result comes from your fetch & parse code...';
}

//your load function.
function loadCourse(results) {
    for(var index in results) {
        var result = results[index]; //result for single course;
        var task = (
            function(result) {
                return function() {
                    saveToDB(result);
                }
            }
        )(result);

        serialTasks.push(task);
    }
    //execute serial tasks for saving results to database or whatever.
    var firstSerialTask = serialTasks.shift();
    nextInSerial(null, firstSerialTask);
}

//pseudo function to save a result to database.
function saveToDB(result) {
    //your code to store in db here.
}

//checks if fetch() is complete for all course codes in your array
//and then starts the serial tasks for saving results to database.
function CheckIfAllCoursesFetched() {
    courseFetchCount++;
    if(courseFetchCount == courseCodes.length) {
        //now process courses serially
        loadCourse(results);
    }
}

//helper function that executes tasks in serial fashion.
function nextInSerial(err, result) {
    if(err) throw Error(err.message);

    var nextSerialTask = serialTasks.shift();
    nextSerialTask(result);
}

//start executing parallel tasks for fetching.
for(var index in courseCode) {
    var course_code = courseCode[index];
    var task = (
        function(course_code) {
            return function() {
                fetch(course_code);
                CheckIfAllCoursesFetched();
            }
        }
    )(course_code);
    parallelTasks.push(task);

    for(var task_index in parallelTasks) {
        parallelTasks[task_index]();
    }
}
```

Or you may refer to [nimble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nimble) npm module.